Handling Entity Framework object cycling / infinite reference looping in many-to-many relationships
Is there a performance cost to using Entity Framework for many to many relationships, and if so, how do I get around it?
For example:
[Table("Movies")]
public class Movie
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Column("MovieId", TypeName = "INTEGER")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column("Title", TypeName = "NVARCHAR(500)")]
    public string MovieTitle { get; private set; }

    public IEnumerable<MovieGenre> MovieGenres { get; set; }
}

[Table("Genres")]
public class Genre
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    Column("GenreId", TypeName = "INTEGER")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column("Name", TypeName = "NVARCHAR(500)")]
    public string GenreName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<MovieGenre> MovieGenres { get; set; }
}

[Table("MovieGenres")]
public class MovieGenre
{
     [Key]
     [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
     [Column("MovieGenreId", TypeName = "INTEGER")]
     public int Id { get; set; }

     [Required]
     public int MovieId { get; set; }
     [ForeignKey(nameof(MovieId))]
     public Movie Movie { get; set; }

     [Required]
     public int GenreId { get; set; }
     [ForeignKey(nameof(GenreId))]
     public Genre Genre { get; set; }
}

I have used an association entity to help tell Entity Framework about the many to many relationship between Movie and Genre in the above example.
The record resolves as such:
var movieToReturn = await _dbContext.Movies
                                    .Include(mov => mov.MovieGenres)
                                    .ThenInclude(movgen => movgen.Genre)
                                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

But because Movie and Genre both have a the navigation property MovieGenres, reference looping occurs with e.g. Movie.MovieGenres.Movie.MovieGenres..., Movie.MovieGenres.Genre.MovieGenres... etc
I have found that the above doesn't cause any major issue to any client requiring JSON data for the above if it is setup to handle this situation (Json Serializer options set to not serialize where circular references exist).
However, I cant make a mental model of a scenario where it doesn't potentially cause memory penalties in the program. I have read that Entity Framework runs the correct number of SQL joins and brings back only a single instance of each object (unique, based on primary key). From there, it constructs an Identity Map, and for any circular reference to the object, it stores and manages them in there as reference type objects.
How does EF manage this efficiently, if there are a large number of records? Surely those references need to be stored in memory, meaning unnecessary storage? Isn't there a way to tell EF to not include these obvious circular references, e.g. when calling .Include().ThenInclude(), maybe a .ThenExclude() to stop the circular reference past a point? Is this available via a Nuget package somewhere?
How does this setup compare to using Dapper with a model to bring back just the data you need?

What do you mean by "reference looping occurs"?  EF should handle this scenario without a significant performance issue.

The term reference looping might not describe the issue effectively, more a circular reference to the Movie and Genre occurs. E.g. calling var movieToReturn = await _dbContext.Movies
.Include(mov => mov.MovieGenres)
.ThenInclude(movgen => movgen.Genre)
.FirstOrDefaultAsync(); causes the Movie and Genre object to be made available in multiple places on that object via references / pointers, e.g. Movie.MovieGenres.Movie.MovieGenres.Movie..., Movie.MovieGenres.Genre.MovieGenres.Movie...

Which is perfectly fine in OO languages.  EF will materialize a single instance of each entity and make sure all the property references are "fixed-up".  Having an object graph in memory with circular references is totally normal.

But a potentially infinite number of circular references just doesn’t seem normal to me, especially when it a. seems to serve no purpose, and b. can be avoided with other technology (e.g. Dapper). Is there no way to tell EF to nullify the objects past a certain point? It seems odd to me that no mechanism has been drawn up for this. Thank you for the responses, I appreciate it!

There's not an "infinite number of circular references".  It's perfectly normal for two or more object instances to reference each other.

Circular references are a normal part of referential structures, but they are not suited to serialization. To avoid performance and resource issues, avoid trying to serialize entities, instead create a DTO structure representing exactly what you want to serialize (i.e. to what depth) and project the EF query into that DTO structure. Entities represent data domain, not transport. Understanding and using projection will avoid 98% of all problems devs encounter with EF.

I have been handling the situation with mapping entities to DTOs with the correct shape of data required (missing the navigation property where not required). I am still concerned that my queries are taking up  memory storing a bunch of pointers for placing data where it is not needed. My concern is likely unnecessary, I just want to understand how those extra pointers being stored (for a potentially infinite number of circular references) aren’t any sort of concern. People have mentioned they aren’t, but not why they aren’t. What is happening behind the scenes with it all?


How does EF manage this efficiently, if there are a large number of records?

It has dictionaries inside ChangeTracker which can find entity via Primary key or Alternale key effeciently.
IStateManager.TryGetEntry

Implementation is here:
https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/main/src/EFCore/ChangeTracking/Internal/StateManager.cs


Isn't there a way to tell EF to not include these obvious circular references, e.g. when calling .Include().ThenInclude(), maybe a .ThenExclude() to stop the circular reference past a point?

Not sure what do you mean. But usually it is done via AsNoTracking()


Is this available via a Nuget package somewhere?

Not everything can be extended.


How does this setup compare to using Dapper with a model to bring back just the data you need?

Just use Select and project what you need in appropriate shape (DTO). Dapper is a simple mapper and eager loading is not his strong side.
